# Probability of drawing Ace after drawing an unknown card without replacement

Tags: probability

You have a shuffled, standard 52 card deck with 4 Aces.

You draw a random card without showing it, and without replacing it into the deck.

What is the probability that the next card will be an Ace? What is the formula to calculate this?

Comment: Try editing your question to tell us what you have tried and why you think it is wrong (or right) then we can help you clarify your thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Without the complication of discarding the top card, the probability clearly is 1/13, or 4/52, since there are 4 aces in the deck.

Now, how does discarding the top card change this? Actually, it doesn't. Because you don't look at it and we assume that each card is equally likely to be in each position in the deck, removing the top card doesn't give you any information you didn't have otherwise.

Comment: This is not right.If the first card is an ace you only have three aces left. So it is 3/51 given a ace was drawn and 4/51 given an ace was not drawn. It would only be 1/13 if you replace the first card at random in the deck.

Comment: @Michael You must be reading the question differently than others are.  Although its assumptions about the makeup of the deck are currently incorrect, the analysis in Zahava Kor's answer nevertheless directly--and correctly--responds to your objection.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is: 4/52 x 3/51 + 48/52 x 4/51 = 194/2652 = 1/13

The first product is the case when you drew an ace first (probability 4/52) and you have 3 aces left, the second product is the case when you did not draw an ace (probability 48/51) and you have 4 aces left. This adds up to 1/13. The name of this formula is "The Total probability Formula".

Comment: The question states the deck has four aces.  Could you explain, then, what you mean by "have 12 aces left" or "have 13 aces left"?

Comment: Sorry - I solved the wrong problem - that of selecting a "club" for example. The right calculation is of course: 4/52 x 3/51 + 48/52 x 4/51 = 194/2652 = 1/13.

Comment: I had thought as much--but why don't you edit your answer to reflect that, so that future readers will not be confused?